# I want to save my data in .pdf file in android

Tags: java, android

I have a data in TableLayout and then i want to write this data in .pdf file. Is any way to do so.
And also the data is received dynamically and displayed in TableLayout, so there is not id for every TextView.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    Log.d("tab",String.valueOf(((TextView) arg1).getText()));
    int i=Integer.parseInt(((TextView) arg1).getText().toString());
    if(i!=0)
    {   
        // tl.bringToFront(); 
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                {
                    if(j==0)
                        tl.removeAllViews();
                    TableRow tr =  new TableRow(context);
                    TextView c1 = new TextView(context);
                    c1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    c1.setText(date[j]);
                    TextView c2 = new TextView(context);
                    c2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    c2.setText(""+drug[j]);
                    TextView c3 = new TextView(context);
                    c3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    c3.setText(""+(j+1));
                    tr.addView(c3);
                    tr.addView(c1);
                    tr.addView(c2);
                    Log.d("DATA SHown","closed");
                    tl.addView(tr);
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android features a nice Print framework now, it features a PrintedPDFDocument, which has a Canvas you can paint to just like any other activity. So in your case you would draw the selected views to the PrintedPDFDocument's Canvas. You can find more information about printing to PDF [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html)

Comment: I understand that the whole view could be drawn on the file, right.but,I don't understand what PrintAttributes does in the parameters. If u can clear my doubt

Comment: You are a little vague and too general, you don't know what the PrintAttributes do? I think you should just check out the API and some tutorial and if you get stuck come back with a precise question regarding some of the print parameters you have trouble with. I used this tutorial once to get me going: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial